# What does the instruction sete do in assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86

My uni course requires some basic assembly knowledge... even though I have NONE. However they gave us this sample assembly code:

```
080485fa <check_pin>:
 80485fa:       55                      push   ebp
 80485fb:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80485fd:       81 7d 08 bf 07 00 00    cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8],0x7bf
 8048604:       0f 94 c0                sete   al
 8048607:       0f b6 c0                movzx  eax,al
 804860a:       5d                      pop    ebp
 804860b:       c3                      ret
```

It is supposed to be more or less equivalent to the following C code:

```
int check_pin(int pin) {
        return pin == 0x7bf;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what exactly this assembly code do and I'm dumbfounded by this `sete` instruction. What does this instruction do?

Wikibooks has [a course on x86 assembly](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly), but I was not able to find anything about `sete` in the chapter devoted to assembly instructions.

Comment: http://felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `sete` instruction (and its equivalent, `setz`) sets its argument to `1` if the zero flag is set or to `0` otherwise.  The zero flag is set if the last comparison or arithmetic instruction yielded equality or a result of zero.  Thus in your case, `sete` sets `al` to `0` or `1` according to the result of the preceeding `cmp` instruction.

Answer (score 6):

It might be a little bit difficult to find `sete` in many manuals, since they don't list it directly, just like `cmove`. One trick is to use the documentation feature on [Godbolt's Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27bool+f(int+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+x+%3D%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+g()%0A%7B%0A++++__asm(%22sete+%25al%22)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.19098235398809,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang700,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O1%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+7.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.80901764601191,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Just write the instruction inline like this

```
__asm("sete %al");
```

`sete al` will also work, since we don't care what the operands are, the only important thing is the mnemonic. Then if you hover the mouse on the word `sete` you'll see the documentation tooltip appears. Now put the cursor on that word and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Another popup will appear

> ## SETE help
>
> Sets the destination operand to 0 or 1 depending on the settings of the status flags (CF, SF, OF, ZF, and PF) in the EFLAGS register. The destination operand points to a byte register or a byte in memory. The condition code suffix (cc) indicates the condition being tested for.

At the end of the popup you'll also see the link to the [documentation for that instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SETcc.html) where you can see this

```
0F 94           SETE r/m8   M   Valid   Valid   Set byte if equal (ZF=1).
REX + 0F 94     SETE r/m8*  M   Valid   N.E.    Set byte if equal (ZF=1).
```

ZF will be set when the result is zero, which also indicates an "equal" condition

Comment: The other way to find documentation is to look up the `0F 94` opcode in an opcode map.  But yeah, nice answer for how to find docs for mysterious instructions.  There are several similar SO questions about AT&T operand-size suffixes confusing people who looked for `retq` or `leal` in the manual, or whatever, as well as setcc/jcc/cmovcc.