# Assembly: CMOVB instruction in Intel x86-64 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

I'm a little confused about what "cmovb" does in this assembly code

```
leal   (%rsi, %rsi), %eax  // %eax <- %rsi + %rsi
cmpl   %esi, %edi          // compare %edi and %esi
cmovb  %edi, %eax
ret
```

and the C code for this is:

```
int foo(unsigned int a, unsigned int b)
{
    if(a < b) 
        return a;
    else
        return 2*b;
}
```

Can anyone help me understand how `cmovb` works here?

Comment: Have you consulted the instruction set reference? `cmovb %edi, %eax` is equivalent to `if (below) eax = edi` where of course "below" refers to a particular condition set previously by the `cmp`. You just need to follow what's in each register.

Comment: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMOVcc.html possible duplicate: [What does the instruction sete do in assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53011701/995714)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jester commented to the question, the `cmov*` family of instructions are conditional moves, paired via the *flags* register with a previous (comparison) operation.

You can use for example the [Intel documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-1-2a-2b-2c-2d-3a-3b-3c-3d-and-4) as a reference for the x86-64/AMD64 instruction set. The conditional move instructions are shown on page 172 of the combined volume.

`cmovb`, `cmovnae`, and `cmovc` all perform the same way: If the carry flag is set, they move the source operand to the destination operand. Otherwise they do nothing.

If we then look at the preceding instructions that affect flags, we'll see that the `cmp` instruction (the `l` suffix is part of AT&T syntax, and means the arguments are "longs") changes the set of flags depending on the difference between the two arguments. In particular, if the second is smaller than the first (in AT&T syntax), the carry flag is set, otherwise the carry flag is cleared; just as if a subtraction was performed without storing the result anywhere.  (The `cmp` instruction affects other flags as well, but they are ignored by the code.)

Comment: "cmovb, cmovnae, and cmovc all perform the same way". Yeah, no wonder. It's the exact same instruction. (`0F 42`)

Comment: @MSalters: Yup. It's very common/typical in this particular instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

`C MOV B` = Conditional MOVe if Below (Carry Flag Set). It literally does what it says, if the condition is met then move. The condition is `a<b` and the value moved is `2*b`

The ABI stores the return value in `%edi`, so it first stores `a` and then conditionally overwrites it with `2*b`.

Comment: Bit of a brainfart there; mixing up ARM and x86 assembly. :|